# how to call Array of java class in jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, resultset

Hello I want to pass my two ResultSet in jsp file. i have two ResultSet rs and rs1. i have stored both ResultSet in Single Array. now i want to print that array in jsp file. so i can show my result on web page.kindly tell me which code i should write in jsp file. how many file i should import in jsp file .. kindly help me.

```
                    try
        {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
            Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lportal","root","ubuntu123");   
            PreparedStatement stmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Testi_Testimonial where subject = ?");
            PreparedStatement stmt1 = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Testi_Testimonial where subject != ?");
            stmt.setString(1,search);
            stmt.execute();
            rs=(ResultSet) stmt.getResultSet();
            stmt1.setString(1,search);
            stmt1.execute();
            rs1=(ResultSet) stmt1.getResultSet();
            while(rs.next())

            {
            count++;
            anArray[i]=rs.getString("subject");
            System.out.println(anArray[i]);
        i++;    
            }

        while(rs1.next())
        {

            anArray[i]=rs1.getString("subject");

            System.out.println(anArray[i]);

            i++;
           }

            }

            catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("problem in connection");
        }
```

This is my java code which contain Resultset and array. kindly help me.

Comment: Check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your resultset in any scope according to your requirement like request or session attribute as:

```
request.setAttribute("resultset", resultset);
```

Now to fetch the data from your scoped attribute(Means to get the array values in your jsp page)

```
<logic:iterate id="item" name="resultset" indexId="idx">
  <tr>
   <td align="center"><bean:write name="idx"/></td>

   <td align="center" ><bean:write name="item" property="eid"/></td>
   <td align="center" ><bean:write name="item" property="fname"/></td>
   <td align="center" ><bean:write name="item" property="lname"/></td>
   <td align="center" ><bean:write name="item" property="designation"/></td>
   <td align="center" ><bean:write name="item" property="email"/></td>
   <td align="center" ><bean:write name="item" property="contact"/></td>
   <td align="center" ><bean:write name="item" property="reqdate"/></td>
   <td align="center" ><bean:write name="item" property="ipaddress"/></td>
   <td align="center" ><html:radio name="item" property="adminchoice"  indexed="true" value="approved" /></td>
   <td align="center" ><html:radio name="item" property="adminchoice"  indexed="true" value="blocked" ></td>
   <td align="center" ><html:radio name="item" property="adminchoice"  indexed="true" value="deleted" /></td>  

  </tr>
  </logic:iterate>
```

Hope it'll help you....!